# Is it good to select the same column on multiple where condition mysql?

Tags: mysql

I'm thinking about counting the number of rows depending on each condition and put each result with alias. I don't know if it possible and good to do it this way. For example:

```
select 
(select sum(buy) from order_db where stts=1) as buy1,
(select sum(buy) from order_db where stts=2) as buy2,
(select sum(buy) from order_db where stts=3) as buy3
from order_db
where date='2021-08-29' and user='john'
```

I've tried but got error in return. I'm a basic sql learner. Please help me with suggestion or a clue to find the answer.

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: It's some silly mistake error like missing comma between select. :(

Comment: Oops! My bad :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN stts=1 THEN buy ELSE 0 END) buy1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN stts=2 THEN buy ELSE 0 END) buy2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN stts=3 THEN buy ELSE 0 END) buy3
FROM order_db
WHERE date='2021-08-29' AND user='john';
```

If there are other values than 1, 2 and 3 for `stts` you may also add to the `WHERE` clause:

```
AND stts IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

So basically, this sounds like you are in need of a "conditional count". This can be achived with the combination of `SUM` and the `CASE WHEN` operator.

Applied to your problem, the solution would be somethinge like this:

```
select 
(sum(case when stts = 1 then buy else 0 end)) as buy1,
(sum(case when stts = 2 then buy else 0 end)) as buy2,
(sum(case when stts = 3 then buy else 0 end)) as buy3
from order_db
where date='2021-08-29' and user='john'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried, but the result is counting the stts instead of buy where stts='1' as I want as first. This is something I want but can you give a suggestion, please?

Comment: Oh i understand, simply replace the `1` in the true twig of the `case when` statement with `buy`

Comment: @Michael, you should edit your answer with the change you are suggesting to make it clear.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.